# Counter-intuitive behavior with virtual functions

Tags: c++

Given

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


struct A  {
    virtual operator std::string() const { return "A"; }
    virtual operator const char *() const { return this->operator std::string().c_str(); }
};

struct B1 : public A {
    virtual operator std::string() const { return "<"; }
};

struct B2 {
    B2() { }
    virtual ~B2() { }
    virtual operator std::string() const { return ">"; }
    virtual operator const char *() const { return this->operator std::string().c_str(); }
};

struct C1 : public A {
    C1() { }
    virtual ~C1() { }
    virtual operator std::string() const { return "["; }
};

struct C2 {
    C2() { }
    virtual ~C2() { }
    virtual operator std::string() const { return "]"; }
    virtual operator const char *() const { return this->operator std::string().c_str(); }
};

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    cout << B1() << endl;
    cout << C1();
    cout << C2() << B2() << endl;
}
```

The output should be "<[]>". However, it is "<[]]".

1. Am I wrong? If so, why?
2. If not, then what are the potential reasons for this behavior?

Comment: Don't think I have ever seen virtual applied to operator before. I am curious how you are going to invoke it.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, the behaviour of your code is undefined due to the following:

```
return this->operator std::string().c_str();
```

You're calling `c_str()` on a temporary, and using the result later on.

What you're seeing is a valid manifestation of undefined behaviour.

Now, if you're curious as to what actually happens under the hood, you could modify the last line of `main()` to read:

```
    cout << (const void*)C2() << ' ' << (const void*)B2() << endl;
```

If you do, you'll probably see the same address getting printed twice (which in both cases is a dangling pointer). This is what happens on my computer, and I suspect what happens on yours. **Of course, since the behaviour is undefined, this is just one possible manifestation of many.**

Comment: The only reason I was using the c_str() hack was because C++11 iostream is non-functional and it's refusing to cast to rvalues. Looks like my workaround will be shared_ptr<char>.

Comment: @moshbear: Or your strings/char* could be references to real objects. Casting sounds like you are doing something else wrong and shared_ptr seems like the completely wrong solution to this.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem really boils down to:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct B2 {
    B2() { }
    virtual ~B2() { }
    virtual operator std::string() const { return ">"; }
    virtual operator const char *() const { return this->operator std::string().c_str(); }
};

struct C2 {
    C2() { }
    virtual ~C2() { }
    virtual operator std::string() const { return "]"; }
    virtual operator const char *() const { return this->operator std::string().c_str(); }
};

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    cout << C2() << B2() << endl;
}
```

Where it is evident that this has nothing to do with virtual functions. What happens here is that `operator const char*` is called, which calls `operator std::string` which returns a temporary `std::string` from which you return the `.c_str()`. Since after the call of `operator const char*` this temporary `std::string` is destroyed, you have a `const char*` pointing to already freed memory.

And now anything can happen, since this is UB...